# PHP Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, json

First of all i know stackoverflow is full from this kind of erros but none of them is like mine so im posting this.

Im trying to get a JSON response from the api and as im trying to echo it im getting the `Trying to get property of non-object` error.

```
$apicalldata = file_get_contents("https://api.digitalocean.com/v1/droplets/?client_id=6356465465363546&api_key=f9a702abe442198a4168346435366436cc4cd2138dfc");

$call = json_decode($apicalldata);

echo $call->droplets->id;
```

This is the code im using. From this i'm expecting a response like this:

```
{
"status": "OK",
"droplets": [
  {
  "id": 100823,
  "name": "test222",
  "image_id": 420,
  "size_id":33,
  "region_id": 1,
  "backups_active": false,
  "ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
  "private_ip_address": null,
  "locked": false,
  "status": "active",
  "created_at": "2013-01-01T09:30:00Z"
}
 ]
 }
```

Any ides why am i having this problem? Also is the `$call->droplets->id` correct?
Thanks for your time

Comment: Your JSON might be invalid and `$call` is NULL. Perhaps `$call` doesn't have a `droplets` key and therefore `$call->droplets` is NULL. If you'd use `var_dump($call, json_last_error())` you'd figure out what's wrong. As far as I can see your URL gives `{"status":"ERROR","error_message":"Access Denied","message":"Access Denied"}`. Did you try to actually *print* the `$apicalldata` variable to see what you receive?

Comment: check what response you are receiving? Maybe you get access error or such

Comment: Try $call->droplets[0]->id. Notice the [0]? Droplets looks to be an array in your sample.

Comment: print_r($call)
will show you the structure of the data you are getting. After     $call[droplets][0][id] should show you the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `droplets` is an array. Give this a try.

```
$droplets = $call->droplets;
$myDroplet = $droplets[0];
$myDropletID = $myDroplet->id;
echo $myDropletID;
```

*** Update after your comment ***

```
$droplets = $call->droplets;

foreach($droplets as $droplet)
{
    $dropletID = $droplet->id;
    echo $dropletID;
}
```

Comment: It worked but is it possible to make it in to a while loop so it will output the ids from every droplet?

Comment: You bet. See my update. FYI, you should get in the habit of putting what you want in your question.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$call = json_decode($apicalldata);
foreach($call->Droplet as $adm)
{
echo "ID ".$adm->id."<br/>";
}
```